# A condition for a subset to be a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if $S$ is a nonempty subset of a vector space $V$, then $S$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $\operatorname{Span}(S)=S$.

Comment: What is your definition of span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $span(S)$ is the minimal subspace (in the sense of inclusion) of $V$ that contains $S$. So if $S=span(S)$, then clearly $S$ is a subspace of $V$. For the other implication, since $S$ is a subspace of $V$ which trivially satisfies $S\subseteq S$, then $span(S)\subseteq S$, but also for definition $S\subseteq span(S)$, hence $S=span(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a non empty subset of $V$.

- Suppose we have $\text{span} (S) =S$. Let $v, w\in S$ and let $c, d$ be scalars. Since $\text{span} (S) =S$, we have $cv+dw\in S$. Therefore $S$ is a subspace of $V$.
- Now suppose conversely that $S$ is a subspace of $V$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction we have $\text{span} (S) \neq S$. Since $S\subseteq \text {span} (S) $,  we must therefore have $\text{span} (S) \not\subseteq S$.  In other words,  there exists $v, w \in S$ and scalars $c, d$ such that $cv+dw\notin S $. But this contradicts the fact that $S$ is a subspace of $V$. Hence we must have $\text{span}(S) =S$.

From the above argument, we can conclude that if $S$ is non empty,  then $S$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $\text{span} (S) =S$.